# Using quantlib in python how do i get the number of days between two dates?

Tags: python, date, quantlib

i have tried this but it isnt working

import QuantLib as ql

ql.Thirty360().yearFraction((6, 6, 2020),(7, 7, 2020))

Comment: _i have tried this but it isnt working_ What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `tuple` values to `ql.Date` values using

```py
date = ql.Date(day, month, year)
```

So, your code would become:

```
import QuantLib as ql

ql.Thirty360().yearFraction(ql.Date(6, 6, 2020), ql.Date(7, 7, 2020))
```

See the docs for more: https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html

Comment: This gives you the distance between dates as a fraction of a year.  The number of calendar days between the dates would be `ql.Date(7, 7, 2020) - ql.Date(6, 6, 2020)`, and the number of days according to the 30/360 convention would be `ql.Thirty360().dayCount(ql.Date(6, 6, 2020), ql.Date(7, 7, 2020))`.